# Django: "split" a form on several pages

Tags: django, forms, pagination, view

First off, I've to admit that I'm totally new to Django.
I'm stuck with a problem, but probably I just don't know how to put it correctly to get appropriate help in the web. Therefore, I appreciate any kind of help and thank you in advance for being patient with me as a newbie.^^

In my models.py, I define several RadioSelects named "choice_1", "choice_2", etc. In my template.html I loop over Django's `form` object to get all the RadioSelects in a table, which works perfectly fine:

```
<table class="table">
    {% for field in form %}
        <tr>{% formfield field %}</tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Here's my problem:

Now I would like to "split" the form on several pages, i.e. I would like to have each single RadioSelect on a separate page within the same HTML template. To do so I searched the net and stumpled over two different ways I could think of in order to handle the problem:

1. [In this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/qyXbCbYIcnc), for instance, the `slice` template filter is recommended. To me, this would seem to be a perfect solution as it could easily be implemented by using `{% for fields in form|slice:":1" %}`. However, I'm not able to get it done with `slice`; actually, it does not appear to change anything.
2. Another idea is some kind of "pagination" or the like. I already found the django-build-in `pagination` classes but I'm not able to get things to work out.

Without any idea how to solve this issue, I would be very grateful for your help. Thank you very much in advance and best wishes, fh_!

Comment: Did you convert to a list as mentioned in the first option?

Comment: @oneyka: Actually, I thought the `form` object is already in list form.

Probably, I should note that I'm working with a Django project called oTree which allows to programm experiments in the field of social sciences.

The docs state that "`form` is a special variable. It is a Django form object, which is an iterable whose elements are Django form field objects. `formfield` can take as an argument a Django field object, or it can be an expression like {% formfield player.foo %} and {% formfield group.foo %}, but player.foo must be written as a literal ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is [Django Form Wizard](https://github.com/django/django-formtools/blob/master/docs/wizard.rst), which is now part of django-formtools rather than in core Django. For each page view, you define a form (in your example, I guess you'd need to define forms rather than rely on modelform implementation) and then wrap those forms in a FormWizard.